# How to check a boolean argument in a command with optional arguments?

Tags: errors, conditionals, expl3, programming

I have a command with an optional argument, and I want to execute some code depending if argument is `true` or `false` (I am sure that this command will have always some argument convertible to a boolean, because it will be a private command, not an user command). With my code I get this error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.8     \test{
              }
?
```

Thanks everybody for any help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\test}[1][true]{
\bool_if:NTF{#1}{\message{true}}{\message{false}}
}
\test{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

First, note that `\bool_if:N(TF)` expects a single token (the `N`-type) as argument, thus `\bool_if:NTF {true} {T}{F}` is syntactically invalid. You'd need the `n`-type argument: `\bool_if:nTF {true} {T}{F}`. However this doesn't work either because `expl3`'s boolean functions don't understand the literals `true` and `false`, so you need to help it understand what you mean.

You can use, for example, `\str_case:nnF` to check the input argument against a number of predefined cases and, if none matches, escape through the `F` branch, which lets `\bool_if:n(TF)` do the parsing:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \test { O{true} }
  {
    \bool_if:nTF
      {
        \str_case:nnF {#1}
          { % Known cases
            { true  } { \c_true_bool  }
            { T     } { \c_true_bool  }
            { 1     } { \c_true_bool  }
            %
            { false } { \c_false_bool }
            { F     } { \c_false_bool }
            { 0     } { \c_false_bool }
          }
          {#1} % Otherwise
      }
      { \iow_term:n {true} }
      { \iow_term:n {false} }
  }
%
\test % no argument
\test[true]  \test[1] \test[T] \test[\c_true_bool]  % true input
\test[false] \test[0] \test[F] \test[\c_false_bool] % false input
\test[\int_compare_p:n { 2+2>4 } && !\c_false_bool] % expressions
%
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

It will print:

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
false
false
false
false
```

Note that this doesn't defend from arbitrarily bad input, it just covers a few extra cases, so you won't be able to use *anything* as input. Also, the literals `true` and `false` are only recognised if used alone. That is, `\test[true]` and `\test[false]` work as expected, but `\test[!true]` will not, because `!true` is not recognized by `\str_case:nn(TF)`, and the literal `true` then goes directly to `\bool_if:n(TF)`, which then fails as before.

Also, if it is a private-use command which you can guarantee that will have an argument, then there is no point in making the argument optional, as it will only slow down the processing.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't give much details about what your command should do. But instead of using arguments "true" and "false" and then doing string comparision on them, it is normally better to use key val syntax in the argument and to set real booleans with them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { alek }
 {
   dothis .bool_set:N = \l__alex_dothis_bool
 }

\newcommand{\test}[1][]
 {
  \keys_set:nn {alek}{dothis=true,#1} 
  \bool_if:NTF\l__alex_dothis_bool
   {true}
   {false}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\test{}

\test[dothis]

\test[dothis=false]

\test[]
\end{document}
```